# Converting a string from JSON to dictionary or tuple

Tags: python-3.x

I extract a string from JSON file in the following format:

```
"voltages":[[0.001953125,-12.5],[0.00390625,-12.5],[0.005859375,-12.5]...]]
```

And I want to transform that combination of two items into a dictionary or tuple, so that I can write it to an Excel file.

What I did was to try to grab the data using regular expression `r'(\[\[.*\]\])+'` or `json.loads`, but then I am at a loss on how to convert the data into a dictionary.

```
{"gain":35.6,"signals":{"trigger":31.73,"baseline":-19.402221696199106,"voltages": 
[[0.001953125,-12.5],[0.00390625,-12.5],[0.005859375,-12.5], 
 [0.0078125,-12.5],[0.009765625,-12.5],[0.01171875,-12.5],[0.013671875,-12.5]...]}}
```

I ended up using the following:

```py
with open(filename, "r") as file:
  data = json.loads(file.read())
  voltages_dict = dict()
  for entry in data['signals']['voltages']:
      voltages_dict[entry[0]] = entry[1]
```

Comment: Sorry, my json was a bit malformed. The file has 25000+ occurrences of those two items that are both inside the JSON array, but it is variable and might get larger in the future, so I abridged it a little. The first element's precision varies and the second element is always a negative float number.

Comment: You should write a separate script to repair the file, then read it in as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given the following in a file called `test.json`

```py
{
    "gain": 35.6,
    "signals": {
        "trigger": 31.73,
        "baseline": -19.402221696199106,
        "voltages": [[0.001953125, -12.5], [0.00390625, -12.5], [0.005859375, -12.5], [0.0078125, -12.5], [0.009765625, -12.5], [0.01171875, -12.5], [0.013671875, -12.5]]
    }
}
```

### Read and extract info from file

```py
from pathlib import Path
import json

# p = Path('test.json')  # if in current dir
# p = Path(r'c:\some_path\test.json')  # if it's not in the current dir
p = Path.cwd() / 'test.json' 

# read the file
with p.open('r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

# extract information
print(data['signals']['voltages'])

[[0.001953125, -12.5],
 [0.00390625, -12.5],
 [0.005859375, -12.5],
 [0.0078125, -12.5],
 [0.009765625, -12.5],
 [0.01171875, -12.5],
 [0.013671875, -12.5]]

# into a dict
voltages_dict = dict()
voltages_dict['voltages'] = data['signals']['voltages']
```

### Malformed JSON

- Try to repair the various issues

```py
# if "signals instead of "signals"

with p.open("r") as file: 
    read_file = file.read()
    read_file.replace('"signals', '"signals"')
    # add additional fixes
    # save file
```

Comment: Hello, this is awesome, but could you please show an example on how to squeeze this data into a dictionary?

Comment: Like this? voltages = dict(data['signals']['voltages'][0],data['signals']['voltages'][1:])

Comment: @MarkPern Only one sample of data is provided, so without the actual full form of the file, it's difficult to write an iterative process to add multiple key value pairs. For example, is the file a list of dicts or some other form?